# Difficulty in understanding a proof.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Statement:** If $E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j$, then $m_*(E)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m_*(E_j)$.
>
> **Proof:** By the definition of exterior measure, for each $j$, there is a countable covering $(Q_{k,j})$ of $E_j$ by closed cubes such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |Q_{k,j}| < m_*(E_j) + \frac{\epsilon}{2j},\  \epsilon > 0.$$
>   Now $E \subseteq \bigcup_{k,j=1}^{\infty}Q_{k,j}$
>   $$\therefore{} E\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j$$
>   $$E_j\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_{k,j}$$
>
> By the monotone property of exterior measure,
>   \begin{align}
> m_*(E) &\leq m_*(\bigcup_{k,j=1}^{\infty}Q_{k,j})\\
> &\leq \sum_{k,j=1}^{\infty}m_*(Q_{k,j})\tag{**}\\
> &= \sum_{k,j=1}^{\infty} |Q_{k,j}|\\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |Q_{k,j}|\right)\\
> &\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(m_*(E_j)+\frac{\epsilon}{2j}\right)\\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m_*(E_j)+\epsilon\\
> \end{align}
>   As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary,
>   $$m_*(E) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m_*(E_j)$$

(Original writting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkwXl.jpg))

The proof here is for countable sub additivity of exterior measure but I am not getting what property is used in step $(**)$ ?

Comment: Have you proved countable subadditivity for cubes in the previous section?

Comment: Yes got it. It means here Ej's need not be cubes? And in step (**) , Q_k,j's are closed cubes so to write this step for closed cube we assume it is true for closed cubes and prove it for any subset, right?

Comment: Yes I think that is what is going on

Comment: Ok you may be right then

Comment: If you're reading Stein and Shakarchi, they do in fact prove this for cubes two pages back in Example 2.